# Transform embedded resource during build using Slow Cheeta

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2013, msbuild-task, slowcheetah

Consider the following scenario:

- I use Slow Cheetah to perform XML tranformations on XML-files.
- These XML-files are embedded resources (and due to my IoC-container I cannot (easily) change this)
- When I build my project, Slow Cheetah performs the tranformations on the files and copies them to the output target, however:
- I need to perform these transformations during build and include the transformed files as embedded resources. This is where I get stuck.

My best guess is to add build Tasks in the project file to perform the transformations.

Any ideas??

Comment: It's been too long ago, I can't remember with absolute confidence. Also, I no longer have access to this codebase so I cannot look it up for you. Sorry.